# Function equal to his Laplace or Mellin transform

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

As the title suggests I am looking for functions $f(s)$ for which $\mathscr{L}\{f(s)\}=f(s)$ or $\mathcal{M}\{f(s)\}=f( s)$ where $\mathscr{L}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ stand respectively for Laplace transform and Mellin transform.

> edit:
>   I confirm it is an « or ». More precisely I am looking for non zero functions invariant for some Integral Transform. For Mellin or Laplace transform, if there is not such functions can you please provide a proof or a hint. Merci

Comment: Is it not meant to be:

$$\mathscr{L} \left\{ f(x) \right\}(s) = \mathcal{M}\left\{f(x) \right\}(s) = F(s) $$

??

Comment: No, it is how written in the post

Comment: Ok, I don't believe there are any functions that can satisfy that condition (outside of $f(s) = 0$). In saying that, I believe there may be confusion between what is written and how I've interpreted (I've gone into more detail below).

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for functions such that $\mathcal{L}[f(x)](s)  = f(s)$, and separately looking for functions such that $\mathcal{M}[f(x)](s)  = f(s)$, analogous to how $\mathcal{F}[e^{-x^2/2}] = e^{-k^2/2}$, right?

Comment: If you meant $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathcal{L}[f(y)](ix)$ then this is the same as $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathcal{F}[f(y)](x)$ except you want $f$ to be analytic. The general solution is to take $f$ analytic and Schwartz on horizontal lines of a strip and set $g = f+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathcal{F}[f]+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}^2}\mathcal{F}[\mathcal{F}[f]]+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}^3}\mathcal{F}[\mathcal{F}[\mathcal{F}[f]]]$.

Answer (score 2):

The function

$$f(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$$

has a Laplace transform

$$F(t) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{s}}$$

which is correct up to a constant.

---

Attempt 2: Note that

$$ \mathcal{L}(t^z) = s^{-z-1} \Gamma(l+1)$$

when $\Re (z)>1$. So if now $0<\Re (z)<1$, let

$$f(t)=\sqrt{\Gamma(z)} t^{-z} + \sqrt{\Gamma(1-z)} t^{z-1}$$

so that we get a Laplace transform

\begin{align}
F(s) &= \sqrt{ \Gamma(z)  \Gamma(1-z) } f(s)\\
&=\sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}} f(s)
\end{align}

So if

\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)} &= 1\\
\implies z &= \frac{\arcsin(\pi)}{\pi}
\end{align}

We have a nontrivial function whose Laplace transform equals itself.

Comment: He hasn't asked for functions involving the Fourier Transform.

Comment: upvoted to cancel the downvote

Comment: @timur - The downvote was for the Fourier Transform that he had original posted. Please consider the editing history before commenting.

Comment: @Argon - This is not what is asked for in the question.

Comment: @DavidG I am having some trouble understanding the question then. I understand it as finding a function whose Laplace transform equals itself, or a function whose Mellin transform equals itself.

Comment: @Argon - Yes, that was my first thought. I asked the user and was told that no, it is exactly as stated in the question.

Comment: @DavidG The question states "$\mathscr{L}\{f(s)\}=f(s)$ *or* $\mathcal{M}\{f(s)\}=f( s)$" (my emphasis). The function I present equals its own Laplace transform.

Comment: @Argon - What you've provided is a solution to $\mathscr{L}_{t \rightarrow s} \left\{f(t)\right\} = f(s)$ not $\mathscr{L}_{t \rightarrow s} \left\{f(s)\right\} = f(s)$. As before, I believe that the solution you've provided is what was intended to be asked, but when pressed the user said no it is as dictated in the question.

Comment: @DavidG I figures that comment as he didn't want solutions to $\mathcal{L} f = \mathcal{M} f$. At any rate, it would be odd indeed to care at all about $\mathcal{L}_{t\to s}\{f(s)\} = f(s) \mathcal{L}_{t\to s}\{1\}$, which is trivial.

Comment: @Argon - I agree, but we must consider that the user may be new to integral transformations and isn't aware of the finer elements of the question posed. I know I've been guilty of that when exploring new areas of Mathematics. 

Regardless, your solution is great - I'm just not sure it's answering the question posed.

Comment: @DavidG Fair enough---really, the asker should elaborate further. I will leave this up unless he indicates that this wasn't what was being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Edit - Not that it makes a difference to the solution I've presented, I will appease those commenters here by modifying my original solution to accomodate 'or' over 'and'...

---

Not sure if you can do anything here in it's current definition

Here you have the following identity that you wish to find functions to comply with:

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}_{t \rightarrow s} \left\{ f(s) \right\}(s) = f(s) \lor \mathcal{M}_{t \rightarrow s} \left\{f(s) \right\}(s) = f(s) \nonumber 
\end{equation}
Given the linearity of both the Laplace and Mellin Transformations this becomes:
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}_{t \rightarrow s}  \left\{ 1\right\}(s) = 1  \lor \mathcal{M}_{t \rightarrow s} \left\{1 \right\}(s) = 1 \nonumber 
\end{equation}
Which is false as:
\begin{equation}
 \mathscr{L}_{t \rightarrow s}  \left\{ 1\right\}(s) = \frac{1}{s}\nonumber
\end{equation}
And the Mellin Transformation doesn't exist (outside of $f(s) = 0$)

As such, under your current definition there are no functions that can satisfy it.

Comment: I believe he's looking for functions such that $\mathcal{L}[f(x)](s)  = f(s)$, and separately looking for functions such that $\mathcal{M}[f(x)](s)  = f(s)$. Sort of like how $\mathcal{F}[e^{-x^2/2}] = e^{-k^2/2}$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog - I specifically asked him that above and he said no. I've also stated that I'm sure there has been a misinterpretation to which he hasn't replied. I can only go by what is provided and the definitions within.

Comment: He's probably objecting to your writing $\mathcal{L}[f(x)](s) = \mathcal{M}[f(x)](s)$, which is not part of his question. At any rate, I would suggest waiting for clarification before giving an answer to a question he obviously did not intend.

Comment: I have answered the question as it is given. I asked for clarification and the user stated it was exactly as posed in the question.

Comment: @eyeballfrog - Under what authority are you able to reject what a user has already clarified when pressed? Can you read the user's mind?

Comment: There is an or in the user's post.

Comment: @rubikscube09 - Please note that his original post did not have an 'or' but was written as an 'and'

Comment: The edit history shows 'or' in all versions.

Comment: @eyeballfrog - Yes, indeed. The user deleted the post and then re-posted. The original has it as 'and' - Hence, my original comment on his question. Am still curious as to how you know exactly what this user is asking for? especially after the user stated directly that the question is exactly as he stated.